# Morita theory for simplicial rings

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, simplicial-stuff

My question is the following: is there an analog of [Morita theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Morita%20equivalence#classical_morita_theorem_11) in the simplicial setting?

I mean, we can define two simplicial rings $A,B$ to be simplicially Morita equivalent is the categories of simplicial modules $Mod(A)$ and $Mod(B)$ are equivalent (or maybe equivalent as simplicial categories?). Is there a result similar to the classical Morita theorem which gives the criterion for two rings to be Morita equivalent?

I tried to google, but I couldn't find anything useful. So I think maybe such an extension is just some trivial formality? Or maybe no one considered that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the version with simplicially enriched equivalences can be proved in exactly the same way. But perhaps the real question is whether there is a _homotopical_ version of the Morita theorem.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you, please, give a reference? Have you seen it somewhere? To be honest, I do not want to repeat the proof of classical Morita theorem, even if it is possible. At least, I don't want to do that if there is a chance that it is already written somewhere =)

Comment: I have not seen a proof, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: @ZhenLin, by a homotopical version do you mean what To\"en calls "derived Morita theory" for DG categories?

Comment: That sounds like what I imagined might exist!

Comment: @ZhenLin, I imagine one can translate this theory to the simplicial setting in a straightforward way.  After all the model structures on DG categories and on simplicially enriched categories have basically the same description.